# What is the difference between the two command lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(data = mpg) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy))

ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ,y=hwy))+geom_point()
```

What is the difference between the two command lines, both of them have the same output?

Comment: There is also a variant of the second line: `ggplot(mpg) + aes(x=displ,y=hwy) + geom_point()`

Comment: Another option to call empty plot: `ggplot() + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy), data = mpg)` In short, 1st one is useful when we use the same data for all layers, 2nd is better when we use different data for each layer.

Answer (score 2):

Both line do the same with your code.

The difference is, in line 2 you pass all arguments to the *ggplot* function and the aesthetic mapping will stay the same for every *geom_* you add to the plot.

It's shorter if you want to reuse the mapping for other geoms, like `geom_line()`. 
Line one is more flexible if you wish to add other geoms to the same plot, as you only passed the data to the *ggplot* function but did the mapping directly in the *geom_point* function.